# How to solve port 80 problem in connecting to MySQL with wamp server from android app?

Tags: android, mysql, apache, port

Inserting data from android app to MySQL, fail to connect port 80.

I used WAMP server,android studio3.0,already setting the firewall to open the port 80,and I don't know how to edit httpd.conf file, help.

Fail massage in android studio:

```
E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (CHANGE-ME)}


W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /xxx.xxx.xx.xx:80
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
        at com.eric.timicaller31.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:48)
W/System.err:     at com.eric.timicaller31.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:19)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't listen on port 80, that's HTTP. It's also an **extremely bad idea** to have your MySQL database exposed to the general internet. The best practice here is to have some kind of API layer that separates your Android application from the database so you can do access control.

Comment: I want to insert app's data to cloud where i can manage the data,can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: HttpStatus: 404 - this is a not found - sounds like a wrong URL or not implemented server code.

Comment: Build a REST API with something like [Laravel](https://blog.pusher.com/build-rest-api-laravel-api-resources/), or find an existing cloud data storage solution which works with your Android application.